# Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage) doesn't work

Tags: libgdx, input

I have an image and I want to make clickable this image. I have already done this a lot of times, but this time doesn't work. Probably because the image is from a class which extends Image:

```
public class BitmapFontGenerale extends Image
{

BitmapFont bitmapFont;
String scritta;
private float x;
private float y;

public BitmapFontGenerale(BitmapFont bitmapFont1, String string, float scale)
{
    bitmapFont = bitmapFont1;
    bitmapFont.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    bitmapFont.getData().setScale(scale);
    scritta = string;
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
{
    bitmapFont.draw(batch,scritta,x,y);
}

public void setX(float x)
{
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(float y)
{
    this.y = y;
}

public float getX()
{
    return x;
}

public float getY()
{
    return y;
}

}
```

This is the code which I used to set the input:

```
image.addListener(new ClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void clicked (InputEvent event, float x, float y)
    {
       Gdx.app.log("CLICKED ", "CLICKED");
    }
});
stage.add(image);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

This code works if image is from Image class and not if it's from a class which extends Image. Note: I need to extend Image class. What's the problem?

Comment: Show us your entire class file please Curio :) Also try logging `Gdx.input.getInputProcessor() == stage` to see if your stage is your actual input processor.

Comment: @Charanor done. The stage isn't the actual input processor

Comment: Wait, why are you extending image to draw a font? Just use the `Label` actor. Also since stage isn't your input processor your problem is 99% that you're using another input processor that overrides the stage one.

Comment: @Charanor but in fact I added Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

Comment: Yes but if you do `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);` then `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(somethingElse);` your stage won't register input. You can only have one input processor at a time. If you want multiple you need to use an `InputMultiplexer`.

Answer (score 1):

You must set size in constructor. If width and height equals 0, no clicks will be detected